# Why is .attr('title') grabbing the previous element's title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

**UPDATE**
Flexslider has a bunch of callback spaces for use which make this possible.

```
after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
```

Thanks everyone

**[LIVE CODE](http://designobvio.us/Titles/)**:
I uploaded the live code for debugging; for making a jsfiddles of this would be rather difficult.

**Problem:**  The function fetchTitle() grabs the previous image title and not the most current?

**Explanation:** I have a function falled `fetchTitles()` which takes a title tag from a the active slide from [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and places it into a varible `targetTitle`.  Then replaces `h1.head_line` with the `targetTitle`

**Script:**(paired down from full script please view live code for full)

```
 function fetchTitles() {
       var targetTitle = $('.flex-active-slide').find('img').attr('title');

        $('.head_line').text(targetTitle);

    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <li class="flex-active-slide">
    <article class="active_work" title="Facebook + Like Pillow">
      <figure> <img title="Facebook + Like Pillow" src="asset/img/1600/slide1_1600.jpg" />
        <figcaption class="sliderCaptions">
          <h1>
            <div class="animate_text"></div>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/104865624796200130935/" ><span>Author:</span> Matthew Harwood</a></h1>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <section class="article_post"></section>
    </article>
  </li>
```

**Addition Information:**

- If you click on the links twice you'll see that the title will update itself.
- The fetch title on document ready comes up unidentified even tho there is an `.flex-active-slide` ready.
- The scripts are at the bottom of the source in a `script2.js`

Comment: More than likely the class isn't instantly added, therefore it hasn't updated at the time of your click event. Try instead using an event within the flexslider plugin if one exists. Start with the documentation, http://flex.madebymufffin.com/index.html -> Advanced tab

Comment: `making a jsfiddles of this would be rather difficult` -- you really should be able to craft a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) of the issue; often I've found that doing that sometimes helps me solve the problem.

Comment: It's not just a timer issue.  If you wait - there is a state not being set when the animation finishes. When you click again, the title changes. What's the logical sequence needed?

Comment: fetchTitles() is being called before the next image is scrolled, so the image that's found is the one that was active before you clicked on the next image.

Comment: So what happens when the code changes on your live link? If we can't see the entire problem here, it's hard for us to help you, and it means this question is Too Localized. Please ensure your question is complete for purposes of others helping you debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a problem with timing. If I introduce setTimeout, the problem is gone

```
function fetchTitles() {
       setTimeout(function()
       {
            var targetTitle = $('.flex-active-slide').find('img').attr('title');

            $('.head_line').text(targetTitle);

       },200);
    }
```

Comment: I accually perfer this method it's way faster than using woothemes callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
var targetTitle = $('.flex-active-slide').find('img').prop('title');
```

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: it's accually still doing it but good catch i'll upload the new code with prop

Comment: According to the table on the blog post for 1.6.1, the title should still be accessed with .attr http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Comment: Dangit, you're right, it still works the same for both. Still, a fiddle would help a *lot*.

Comment: The html he gave us has a "title" *attribute* on the image, so why should he use .prop?

Comment: Good explanations also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class isn't updating until after the slide animation has finished, but fetchTitles is running as soon as you click, so the image with the 'flex-active-slide' class is still the previous image.

You may want to look into running fetchTitles in a callback function so it runs after the slide has completed.